# How can the broker get the message from jdbc persistent storage?

Tags: activemq-classic

I want to ask feasibility about actimvemq's configuration. I have to guarantee four conditions.

1) Each producer, consumer and broker in one server are loaded on same one jvm.

2) Each producer in one server have to deliver messages to the consumer of same server.

3) if one of servers is killed and remained some messages in the server, I want the other server's broker to get the messages of killed node and execute instead of killed node. the message would be in the jdbc database store.

Could you recommend the alternative way or give an explanation for this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The dilemma is that you want to have an Active-Active setup (Cluster I assume) but want fail over as well inside the cluster.

You can't get the active nodes picking up the failed brokers DB and continue from there. What you can do is to create an additional setup of brokers on each machine, acting as slaves to the first ones.

Look at the docs
http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html

Then each machine has a fail over for another machine. This way no message will get stranded (assuming only one machine is failing). This won't cost that much more than a bit of RAM to keep the slave idle. However, the solution is kinda complex to host and maint over time.

I don't think you need to do much on the client side as they connect to the local broker (if the server is down, so is the producer/consumer).

[image: Cluster + Master Slave]

Comment: thanks very much for your good idea. for implementation, I have something to ask.

Comment: with this architecture, each producer in one server have to deliver messages to the consumer of same server?

Comment: and I have to have one same database, not four databases.

Comment: What I mean is actually not four db servers or instances, but rather logical databases (like four logical MySQL databases on the same server/installation). 

You can also put up all those four brokes in a network of brokers so that all queues are cluster queues. You can make a pair of consumer/producer connect to "broker2" with failover so that it tries another machine if the first is down. But before you start with such a complex setup, please spend some time studying the documentation throughly. Such an architecture needs to be really though through from the requirement side of things.

Comment: yes I understood. I need four logical databases at least. so each broker have to use one logical database seperately. right?

Comment: I should change my direction. I thought that brokers can share messages if i set the same jdbc persistent adapter to each broker. is it impossible and make it duplicated key exception?